# Imported Golang Package Saying Undefined / Not Available

Tags: go, import, package

So I want to create a library that I can use from a script / project I'm building. The library is called go_nessus, (full source code: http://github.com/kkirsche/go-nessus) but I'm having an issue when importing it.

An example of the go_nessus code:

```
# go-nessus/client
package go_nessus

import (
    "fmt"
)

func (nessus *Nessus) MakeClient(host, port, accessKey, secretKey string) Nessus {
    return Nessus{
        Ip:        fmt.Sprintf("%s", host),
        Port:      fmt.Sprintf("%s", port),
        AccessKey: fmt.Sprintf("%s", accessKey),
        SecretKey: fmt.Sprintf("%s", secretKey),
    }
}
```

When attempting to use this though I get the following error:

```
~/g/G/s/g/k/attempt ❯❯❯ go install -race && $GOPATH/bin/attempt
# github.com/kkirsche/attempt
./attempt.go:6: undefined: go_nessus.MakeClient
```

The test file looks like so:

```
package main

import "github.com/kkirsche/go-nessus"

func main() {
    nessusClient := go_nessus.MakeClient("localhost", "8834", "ExampleAccessKey", "ExampleSecretKey")
}
```

I sadly though can't figure out how to actually use the methods I've created without errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated in figuring out what's wrong with my import process.

My `go env`:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/Users/kkirsche/git/Go/bin"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/kkirsche/git/Go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=""
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Comment: FWIW you should avoid underscores in package names - `nessus` or `gonessus` would be better. See here: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem lies here:

```
func (nessus *Nessus) MakeClient(host, port, accessKey, secretKey string) Nessus {
```

and here:

```
    nessusClient := go_nessus.MakeClient("localhost", "8834", "ExampleAccessKey", "ExampleSecretKey")
```

in your package, you are making the function a member of type `Nessus`
but in main you call it as though it were a package level function

I believe you want `MakeCliet` to be defined as:

```
func MakeClient(host, port, accessKey, secretKey string) Nessus {
```

which makes it a package level function.

Also, you may want to use pointers here if you don't want to copy the struct around all the time, which would be:
    func MakeClient(host, port, accessKey, secretKey string) *Nessus {

and then:

```
return &Nessus{ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a pointers issue. The code should be:

```
package gonessus

import (
    "fmt"
)

func (nessus Nessus) MakeClient(host, port, accessKey, secretKey string) *Nessus {
    return &Nessus{
        Ip:        fmt.Sprintf("%s", host),
        Port:      fmt.Sprintf("%s", port),
        AccessKey: fmt.Sprintf("%s", accessKey),
        SecretKey: fmt.Sprintf("%s", secretKey),
    }
}
```